# why am I receiving duplicate error to a not unique feature of my schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, mongoose-schema, postman-collection-runner

this is part of my userSchema

```
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength:8
},
passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please Confirm your password!"]      
},
```

I am receiving duplicate error in postman from the mongo db, I did not set uniqueness of password, why is mongodb forcing it to be unique? Below is the error I am getting

MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: password_1 dup key: { password: "Debrenu.selam23" }
    at MongoError.create (C:\Users\mekse\Desktop\BACK UP BACK END - Copy - Copy\back end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:59:12)
    at toError (C:\Users\mekse\Desktop\BACK UP BACK END - Copy - Copy\back end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:130:22)
    at C:\Users\mekse\Desktop\BACK UP BACK END - Copy - Copy\back end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:258:39
    at handler (C:\Users\mekse\Desktop\BACK UP BACK END - Copy - Copy\back end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\replset.js:1211:22)
    at C:\Users\mekse\Desktop\BACK UP BACK END - Copy - Copy\back end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:407:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

my code is only working well when I enter all unique values in all sections, name, email,password, password confirm and photo. if the next user uses a duplicate of any of these, it throws an error?
I can not understand why is this? please!  can you help me guys?

Comment: Uniqueness is ultimately enforced by indexes in the database. The error shows that you have a unique index on the password field. If you don't want that then you should drop that index in the database